# Does JSDOM support media queries?

Tags: css, unit-testing, jsdom

I know that JSDOM does not implement many of the bells and whistles of a real browser, but I've read a lot of conflicting information about exactly what it does and does not support regarding CSS. I have confirmed with my own testing that it does parse CSS, but responsive styles don't seem to be working... Does JSDOM support media queries at all?

Comment: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform

Comment: Thanks @Sean that's a helpful link. It does not directly answer my question about media-queries, but it certainly makes it sound unlikely that they are supported.

Comment: There's no layout being implemented, and no viewport or device type, so I would be surprised if they were supported.

Comment: That’s a good point. Want to submit an answer I can accept?

Comment: Thanks. I can't speak authoritatively on it though, so will just leave as a comment in case anyone knows for certain.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in jsdom that container queries cause errors:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3597

> #### Using @container query logs error
>
> Looks like this is implemented by cssom and there is open issue there: NV/CSSOM#109 and not being tackled rrweb-ccsom used currently by jsdom.

It's caused by (no longer maintained) CSSOM which is internally used by jsdom to parse stylesheets:
https://github.com/NV/CSSOM/issues/109

> #### Error: Could not parse CSS stylesheet
>
> cssom@0.5.0 not support @container ,@layer

As you see in these issues, jsdom does not support container queries. jsdom could even throw errors if it encounters container queries, e.g. when using CSS-in-JS engines like Styled Components.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35815615)

Comment: @kamentk added essential parts of the issues (unfortunately, there is not a lot of info)